# How to use keyword spotting feature for IBM Waston Speech to text API?

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am using IBM Watson Speech to text API to convert audio files into text. Every feature is working fine for me. But I am unable to use the Keyword Spotting feature. The output is not giving any info regarding spotted keywords.

Here is my code:

```
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
    service.setUsernameAndPassword("*********", "********");
    //SpeechModel model =service.getModel("en-US_NarrowbandModel");


    service.setEndPoint("https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api");

    String[] keys= {"abuse","bullying","parents","physical","assaulting"};
    RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions().contentType("audio/wav").model("en-US_NarrowbandModel").continuous(true).inactivityTimeout(500).keywords(keys).keywordsThreshold(0.7);


    File audio = new File("C:\\Users\\AudioFiles\\me.wav");

    SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio, options);
    //Speech t1 = service.recognize(audio, options);
    System.out.println(transcript);
```

Is there any special function to get the spotted keywords as output as well with the transcript?

Comment: There was a bug in the Java-SDK. Can you check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in the Java SDK `v3.2.0`. Make sure you download the latest version (`4.2.1`) jar: [java-sdk-4.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases/download/java-sdk-4.2.1/java-sdk-4.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar) or update your Gradle/Maven to pull the latest version.

The code below is based on the code in your question.

```
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

File audio = new File("C:\\Users\\AudioFiles\\me.wav");    

RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions().Builder()
  .contentType("audio/wav)
  .inactivityTimeout(500)
  .keywords({"abuse", "bullying", "parents", "physical", "assaulting"})
  .keywordsThreshold(0.5)
  .build();

  SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio, options).execute();
  System.out.println(transcript);
```